# Specify line length in Geometry Generator QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I'm working in Geometry Generator trying to produce a line from a point in an x,y direction with a specific length of 50m.  I have the direction and line but I can't figure out how to specify the length.

```
make_line($geometry,make_point(x($geometry)+ "A-R-Xvalue",y($geometry)+ "A-R-Yvalue"))
```

Field example
[image]

Comment: make_line() only takes points as arguments, your beginning and ending point determine it's length https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#make-line The distance between your points is in CRS's units not necessarily in meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you MrXsquared! I poked around a bit more and I worked out a solution.

```
make_line($geometry,project($geometry,50,radians("Direction")))
```

"Direction" is azimuth in radians clockwise, where 0 corresponds to north

Answer (score 2):

Given a your layer is in a projected *(metric)* CRS, this should do it:

```
make_line($geometry,project($geometry,50,atan2("A-R-Yvalue","A-R-Xvalue")))
```

Since I dont know what your field contains you may need to adjust the content of `atan2()`. It expects *atan2(dy: y coordinate difference,dx: x coordinate difference)*. In pseudocode:

```
deltaX = x2 - x1
deltaY = y2 - y1
radians = atan2(deltaY, deltaX)
projectedpoint = project(startpoint,distance,radians)
line = make_line(startpoint,projectedpoint)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It somewhat works for me.  The line direction is off but it might have to do with my fields.  I added an example to the question.  My CRS is in a metric projection.

Comment: I also have the x,y data in compass degrees.